# Error while using same table data twice during inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, inner-join

Suppose I have a table, in Database name 'Old', as below:

```
TABLE A
(
    SeniorVehicle varchar(255),
    SeniorVehicleAllowance int,
    JuniorVehicle varchar(255),
    JuniorVehicleAllowance int
    ManagerVehicle varchar(255),
    ManagerVehicleAllowance int

);
```

And another table, in Database name 'New' as below:

```
TABLE B
(
    SeniorVehicle int,
    SeniorVehicleAllowance int,
    JuniorVehicle int,
    JuniorVehicleAllowance int,
    ManagerVehicle int,
    ManagerVehicleAllowance int
);
```

I want to bring the data from TABLE A of Database 'Old' to TABLE B of Database 'New'.

The thing is that, there is a table named Vehicle in both databases as bellow:

```
TABLE Vehicle
(
    VehicleID int pk,
    VehicleName varchar(255)
)
```

Values in SeniorVehicle, JuniorVehicle and ManagerVehicle columns in TABLE A are the VehicleName value in TABLE Vehicle. But the value of SeniorVehicle, JuniorVehicle and ManagerVehicle that must be stored in TABLE B must be the value of VehicleID column in the Vehicle Table.

How to achieve this without error????

I have tried the following:

```
INSERT INTO B
(SeniorVehicle, SeniorVehicleAllowance, JuniorVehicle, JuniorniorVehicleAllowance, ManagerVehicle, ManagerVehicleAllowance)

SELECT Vehicle.VehicleID, c.SeniorVehicleAllowance, c.VehicleID, c.JuniorVehicleAllowance, c.VehicleID, c.ManagerVehicleAllowance

FROM (SELECT b.SeniorVehicle, b.SeniorVehicleAllowance, Vehicle.VehicleID, b.JuniorVehicleAllowance, b.VehicleID, b.ManagerVehicleAllowance

FROM (SELECT a.SeniorVehicle, a.SeniorVehicleAllowance, a.JuniorVehicle, a.JuniorVehicleAllowance, Vehicle.VehicleID, a.ManagerVehicleAllowance

FROM (SELECT SeniorVehicle, SeniorVehicleAllowance, JuniorVehicle, JuniorVehicleAllowance, ManagerVehicle, ManagerVehicleAllowance FROM A) as a

Inner join
Vehicle

ON a.ManagerVehicle = Vehicle.VehicleName) as b

Inner join
Vehicle

ON b.JuniorVehicle = Vehicle.VehicleName) as c

Inner join
Vehicle

ON c.SeniorVehicle = Vehicle.VehicleName
```

I get the following error:

```
The column 'VehicleID' was specified multiple times for 'c'
```

My Databse is MSSQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reformatting your current query gives:

```
SELECT
            Vehicle.VehicleID, 
            c.SeniorVehicleAllowance, 
            c.VehicleID, 
            c.JuniorVehicleAllowance, 
            c.VehicleID, 
            c.ManagerVehicleAllowance

FROM (
    SELECT      b.SeniorVehicle, 
                b.SeniorVehicleAllowance, 
                Vehicle.VehicleID, 
                b.JuniorVehicleAllowance, 
                b.VehicleID, 
                b.ManagerVehicleAllowance

    FROM (
        SELECT      a.SeniorVehicle, 
                    a.SeniorVehicleAllowance, 
                    a.JuniorVehicle, 
                    a.JuniorVehicleAllowance, 
                    Vehicle.VehicleID, 
                    a.ManagerVehicleAllowance

        FROM (
            SELECT      SeniorVehicle, 
                        SeniorVehicleAllowance, 
                        JuniorVehicle, 
                        JuniorVehicleAllowance, 
                        ManagerVehicle, 
                        ManagerVehicleAllowance 
            FROM A
        ) as a

        Inner join  Vehicle
            ON      a.ManagerVehicle = Vehicle.VehicleName
    ) as b

    Inner join  Vehicle
        ON      b.JuniorVehicle = Vehicle.VehicleName
) as c

Inner join  Vehicle
    ON      c.SeniorVehicle = Vehicle.VehicleName
```

In this query, the sub query aliased `c` has two columns called `VehicleID` (which is what your error message is telling you.

The smallest change to fix the issue is to alias the columns in the sub query, e.g:

```
SELECT
            Vehicle.VehicleID AS SeniorVehicleId, 
            c.SeniorVehicleAllowance, 
            c.JuniorVehicleId, 
            c.JuniorVehicleAllowance, 
            c.ManagerVehicleID, 
            c.ManagerVehicleAllowance

FROM (
    SELECT      b.SeniorVehicle, 
                b.SeniorVehicleAllowance, 
                Vehicle.VehicleID AS JuniorVehicleId, 
                b.JuniorVehicleAllowance, 
                b.ManagerVehicleID, 
                b.ManagerVehicleAllowance

    FROM (
        SELECT      a.SeniorVehicle, 
                    a.SeniorVehicleAllowance, 
                    a.JuniorVehicle, 
                    a.JuniorVehicleAllowance, 
                    Vehicle.VehicleID AS ManagerVehicleID, 
                    a.ManagerVehicleAllowance
-- Rest ommited for brevity
```

It would be also possible to re-write the query with more joins, and omit the need for the subqueries altogether also:

```
SELECT      srmgr.VehicleId AS SeniorVehicleId, 
            A.SeniorVehicleAllowance, 
            jrmgr.VehicleId AS JuniorVehicleId, 
            A.JuniorVehicleAllowance, 
            mgr.VehicleId AS ManagerVehicleId, 
            A.ManagerVehicleAllowance 
FROM A

INNER JOIN  Vehicle AS mgr
    ON      a.ManagerVehicle = mgr.VehicleName

INNER JOIN  Vehicle AS jrmgr
    ON      a.ManagerVehicle = jrmgr.VehicleName

INNER JOIN  Vehicle AS srmgr
    ON      a.ManagerVehicle = srmgr.VehicleName
```